# How to rebuild site after editing twig files?

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.1

There is an old site on Symfony2.
I edited one of the twig-files.
The content of the page remains the same.

I tried:
Cleared app/cache folder.
Restarted apache server.
Reloaded browser with Ctrl+F5.

How to "rebuild" the site after editing twig files?

Comment: Did you run cache:clear with the appropriate environment? You run the console with `--env=prod` for instance

Comment: There is no app/console or bin/console files in the project.
Cannot run "composer install" because of problem with mongodb drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I haven't noticed that the site are hosted from a virtual machine. Thus, files in the standard location were ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way for Symfony2 then would be:

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

However, make sure that `app/cache` is writable. Otherwise you'll have 500's with it not being able to write to cache anymore. You could also get specific with your environments like `app/cache/dev` or `app/cache/prod`. The next time your app loads it will take a bit more time, so if you are running a time-sensitive application (hopefully not with Symfony2) then plan that change accordingly.

Comment: app/cache is empty

Comment: Ok, and you are still seeing the old rendering?

Comment: Yes. I open page in incognito window with disabled browser cache.

Comment: Are you sure you updated the correct twig file? As in what did you do that you should see differently?